# Play-authenticate authorization via Facebook

Tags: dependency-injection, oauth-2.0, guice, playframework-2.5, play-authenticate

I'm trying to use play-authenticate (0.8.1 snapshot) in play 2.5 app.
According ([to given example,](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage)) I've added Facebook provider to `MyModule`.

```
bind(FacebookAuthProvider.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

And then got NPE:

```
at com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.ext.ExternalAuthProvider.getRedirectUrl(ExternalAuthProvider.java:70)
at com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.oauth2.OAuth2AuthProvider.getParams(OAuth2AuthProvider.java:187)
at com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.oauth2.OAuth2AuthProvider.getAuthParams(OAuth2AuthProvider.java:156)
at com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.oauth2.OAuth2AuthProvider.getAuthUrl(OAuth2AuthProvider.java:150)
at com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.oauth2.OAuth2AuthProvider.generateRedirectUrl(OAuth2AuthProvider.java:243)
at com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.oauth2.OAuth2AuthProvider.authenticate(OAuth2AuthProvider.java:236)
at com.feth.play.module.pa.PlayAuthenticate.handleAuthentication(PlayAuthenticate.java:376)
at com.feth.play.module.pa.controllers.Authenticate.authenticate(Authenticate.java:20)
```

Does anyone know how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

have you set the file called mine.conf  in /conf/playauthenticate ?